# Angular 8 BehaviorSubject can't change the desired value

Tags: angular, angular8, behaviorsubject

I have a service called `global` which contains global variables used all among the app. One of these variable is the language, where user can change it from one into another. On click, the following method should run to change the app direction:

changeDir()
  {
    this.dirService.changeAppDir.next('rtl');
  }

The `dirService` is imported into the component and the `BehaviorSubject` is being accessed `changeAppDir` using `next` to change the value.

The dirService is having the following script:

```
export class AppDirService {
  changeAppDir = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  dirValue = this.changeAppDir.asObservable();
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to change the global var language value into the new one changed by `next()` so the app direction will change.

Here is the global-var script:

```
export class GlobarVarService {
  defaultLang:string  ;
  defaultDir:string = "ltr" ;
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

`defaultDir` is being binded to different element of the app.

Any idea as it is the first time I use the behavior subject aspect?

Comment: So you need to change the url? the variable is in the window scope?

Comment: @Robertgarcia Not the url. The language of the app. How to connect the `globarVar` variable of language into the behaviorSubject created in the other service to monitor if the user changing the lang or not

Comment: Just declare your globalVarService in the AppDirService constructor and change it from it

Comment: But your AppDirService only has the properties to propagate direction changes. There's no property on it that could also propagate the language changes. You'll have to add them in case you want to propagate the language changes as well.

Comment: Can you fork [this StackBlitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/parent-child-communication-with-input-and-output?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmain-nav%2Fmain-nav.component.ts) and try to replicate your current issue in there and share the updated stackblitz with us so that someone could have a look?

Answer (score 0):

Your appDirService:

```
export class AppDirService {
  changeAppDir = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  dirValue = this.changeAppDir.asObservable();
  constructor(private _globalVar: GlobalVarService) {

  }

  changeDir(value) { 
   this._globalVar.setDefaultLang(value);
   this.dirService.changeAppDir.next(value); 
  }

}
```

In your GlobalVarService:

```
export class GlobarVarService {
  defaultLang:string  ;
  defaultDir:string = "ltr" ;
  constructor() {
  }

  setDefaultLang(value) {
    this.defaultLang = value;
  }
}
```